# How can I execute multiple functions on click(or on change) in sibling components?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and I am developing a basic app. I have several sibling components, button in one of them. By clicking the button I have to trigger several functions in the other components. (The button click fills up an array with data, so maybe the functions can be triggered when a change in the array occurs.)How can this be done?

I tried: @Input-@Output, EventEmmiters, Services, Observables and Subscription, @Viewchild and didn't succeed...The data is traveling between the components, but no functions are called. So any other ideas?(or an example for the ones I've tried, maybe I am doing something wrong)

Service:

```
import { Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VisualService {

  public dataArray = [];

  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.dataArray);
  currentArray = this.dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  updateData(array) {
    this.dataSource.next(array);
    this.dataArray = array;
    console.log(this.dataArray);
  }
}
```

Component that i want to trigger function from:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogComponent } from '../dialog/dialog.component';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { VisualService } from '../services/visual.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('dataTable', { read: MatTable, static: false }) dataTable: any;

  @Input() public formDataArray;

  public dataArray = [];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'surname', 'age', 'action'];

constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private _visualService: VisualService) { }

  openDialog(customer) {
    this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._visualService.currentArray
      .subscribe(arrayData => {
        this.dataArray=arrayData
        console.log(this.dataArray)
        //this.dataTable.renderRows(); -- this is the line that i want to use to redraw a Angular Mat table...but it displays that the table is undefined...//

      });
  }
```

Comment: Don't tell us what you tried, show the code for what you tried. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a mat-table, you should actually connect the observable to the data source directly, rather than storing it in an array.  No need to deal with the subscription yourself when the Material Table will handle it for you.

Component:

```
constructor(readonly dialog: MatDialog, readonly visualService: VisualService) { }
```

Template:

```
<table mat-table [datasource]="visualService.currentArray">
  ...
</table>
```

---

### ORIGINAL

What you want to do is you want to create a global service, and in that service specify a Subject.  Subscribe to the Subject in any of the components that need to be triggered from it.  When the button is clicked, update the subject.

Service

```
private readonly source = new Subject<any[]>();
readonly dataChanged = this.source.asObservable();

updateData(data: any[]) {
  this.source.next(data);
}
```

P.S. Make sure you unsubscribe from the subject when the component is destroyed, I recommend using the takeUntil pattern.

```
/** Handle on-destroy Subject, used to unsubscribe. */
private readonly destroyed = new ReplaySubject<void>(1);

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.dataChanged.takeUntil(this.destroyed).subscribe(
    (data: any[]) => {
      // Do what you need here
    }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  // Unsubscribes all pending subscriptions.
  this.destroyed.next();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick answer. I tried something like that and didn't work. I will edit my post above with the code.

Comment: @StevenK. Seeing that you are using an Angular Material Table, the way this should be implemented changes a little bit(and gets easier).  I've updated my answer to reflect this.